# What does the trim function mean in this context?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Database I'm using: https://uploadfiles.io/72wph**

```
select acnum, field.fieldnum, title, descrip

from field, interest

where field.fieldnum=interest.fieldnum and trim(ID) like 'B.1._';
```

What will the output be from the above query?

Does `trim(ID) like 'B.1._'` mean that it will only select items from `B.1._ column`?

Comment: `trim` removes whitespaces from start and end, so it will select all rows where id contains symbols `b.1` surrounded by 0 or more spaces

Answer (score 3):

trim removes spaces at the beginning and end.
 "_" would  allow representing any character.  Hence query select  any row that starts with  "B.1."

```
 For eg. 
'B.1.0' 
'B.1.9'
'B.1.A'
'B.1.Z'
```

etc

Optional Wildcard characters allowed in like are % (percent) and _ (underscore).
  A % matches any string with zero or more characters.
  An _ matches any single character.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the DB you are using but trim usually remove spaces around the argument you give to it.
The ID is trimmed to be sure to compare the ID without any white-space around it.

About your second question, Only the ROWS with an ID like 'B.1.' will be selected.

[SQL like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

[SQL WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)